# Does $\{a:a=bc\text{ for }b,c\in\mathbb{Q},\text{ and }b\le t,\text{ }c\le u\}$ contain all rationals $a\le tu?$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers, rational-numbers

Note that $t,u\in\mathbb{R},$ and $t,u>0.$ What if, for some $a\le tu,$ all possible candidates $b,c$ reside in outer scope? If the above statement (in the title) is true, the proof must be the form of contradiction, showing that there is no such case. However, other than that, I have no clue where to start the proof from, **so any hints would be greatly appreciated**.

---

This was used in [this text](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~mdamron/teaching/F12/MAT_215_powers.pdf). On page 5 in the proof that $(r^t)^u=r^{tu}$ (for real numbers) the author writes:

> So let $a \le tu$ be rational and assume further that $a > 0$. In this case we can write $a = bc$ for $b, c \in \mathbb Q$
>   and $b \le t$, $c \le u$.

Comment: Note given any nonzero rational $b \in \mathbb{Q}$ then we get the multiplication map $m_b: [x,y] \cap \mathbb{Q} \to [bx, by] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ which sends a rational $r \mapsto b r$ is a bijection of these intervals with inverse given by $m_{b^{-1}}$.

Comment: BTW where does the problem come from? Is it homework assignment from some course? Is it exercise from a book? (If it is from a book, stating the name of the book and number of exercises would give answerers some idea which properties can be used and which properties can't be used. This is part of providing [context for the question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak It's from [this lecture note](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~mdamron/teaching/F12/MAT_215_powers.pdf). When the author tries to prove $(r^{t})^{u}$ for $t,u\in\mathbb{R},$ he mentioned (on the 5p) that "In this case we can write $a=bc$ for $b,c\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $b\le t,c\le u.$"

Comment: I have included it into your question. (Since the context of the question belong, well, into the question.) If you have further improvements or if I misrepresented something, go ahead and edit the post further.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I've posted many questions on this site, based on the understanding that people give more attention to **simple and short questions**. Now that I've heard what you said, it's been **total waste of time** to summarize all the contexts and nitty-gritty details. Thank you for pointing out. I will give more details in the next time.

Comment: I certainly did not intend to say that adding details is waste of time. Quite the opposite, I think that question should contain all necessary details. However, we have rather digressed from your original question. So, if needed, we should [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2016/10/8).

Comment: @MartinSleziak **Oh, I meant to agree with you :)** I tended to make questions short and simple, thereby sometimes missing many useful details. After I heard what you said, I found the need for more room for details and contexts! If the above comment sounded offensive, I'm really sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is not true if you allow $u$ and $v$ to be negative. (This was already pointed out in another answer.)

---

**EDIT:** Even after the reformulation the claim is not true. (Which I did not notice and posted an incorrect proof before.)

To see this, consider $t=u=\sqrt2$ and $a=2$.

If we want to get $a=bc$ for some *positive* rational numbers $b$, $c$, then necessarily $b<\sqrt2$, $c<\sqrt2$ and, consequently $bc<2=a$.

---

If we allow $b$ and $c$ to have *negative* values, then the claim is trivial, since we could take $b=-1$ and $c=-a$.

---

Let us try to prove this claim, which should be valid:

> If $a<tu$ for $a\in\mathbb Q$, $t,u\in\mathbb R$ such that $t,u>0$, then there exist rational numbers $b,c\in\mathbb Q$ such that $a=bc$ and $0<b<t$, $0<c<u$.

- Let us choose first some $b\in\mathbb Q$ such that $a<bu<tu$. (In the other words, take any rational number $b$ between $a/u$ and $t$.)
- We can now simply put $c=a/b$. Then we have $a=bc$ and
  $$c = \frac ab < u.$$

Comment: I haven't learned the things you mentioned above. Can the proof be done without the knowledge of continuity?

Comment: @Il-seobBae I think that if you look at a bit closer at this argument, you will find out that all you need is that it is monotone and bijective. (Although some parts can be stated in a clearer way if we use continuity.) So you could simply tried to check whether you can provide a different argument in the steps where I wrote that I am using continuity.

Comment: @Il-seobBae Only now I see that my previous attempt was incorrect. (Sorry for that.) I have tried to post a new one. It does not use continuity at any point. (Although the idea of continuity is implicitly behind the basica idea of the argument.)

Comment: You start with: "If $a=tu$ for $a\in\mathbb Q$", but later $a <bu <tu$, which is clearly impossible if $a=tu$. Did you mean "If $a<tu$ for $a\in\mathbb Q$"?

Comment: @TonyK Thanks for noticing. Yes, that's what I meant. (I took the claim from the question, but changed $a\le tu$ to $a<tu$.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I think $0<a<t,0<b<u$ should be $0<b<t,0<c<u$. Am I right?

Comment: @Il-seobBae Yes, you are right. The number of mistakes I managed to do in such short space is really embarassing.

Comment: @MartinSleziak In $ab=c$, did you meant $a=bc$?

Comment: @MartinSleziak Now that the old claim is not true, the proof given in this lecture note has no chance for salvage? We proved for $a<tu$, not for $a\le tu$...

Comment: @Il-seobBae If we are able to prove $\{\sup r^a; a\in\mathbb Q\text{ and }a\le t\}=\{\sup r^a; a\in\mathbb Q\text{ and }a<t\}$, then we could use the latter as an alternative definition for $r^t$. My guess is that using this definition, the proof might work. (Although I did not check all details. As I said, it is just a guess.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you for guiding me so far. I really appreciate it. Have a good day!

Answer (score 6):

all. This appears indeed to be a problem. I think the simplest fix is to show that for all real numbers $a$, the sets $\{r^b : b \in \mathbb{Q}, b \leq a\}$ and $\{r^b : b \in \mathbb{Q}, b < a\}$ have the same supremum. This way, you can use the argument posted above to the second set. These suprema are equal essentially by a continuity argument. I can provide some details for this if it is helpful. (I emailed them to the two people who emailed me.)

I wrote these notes sometime around 2012 or so when I was teaching analysis at Princeton during my postdoc. They are part of a larger document which basically trudges through Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis. These properties of real powers are part of an exercise that is in Chapter 2, I think.

Comment: It's so nice of you to come here and answer me back. Despite some errors in this note, I really love the contents inside because unlike Rudin it covers the powers of $\mathbb{N},\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{R}$ thoroughly (and it's also easy to read) .

Answer (score 4):

HINT: What is the set in question when $t=u=-1$?

**Added:** Now that we have it, I’ll address the underlying question of why the following statement is true:

> So let $a \le tu$ be rational and assume further that $a > 0$. In this case we can write $a = bc$ for $b, c \in \mathbb Q$
>   and $b \le t$, $c \le u$.

If $a=tu$, then of course we can take $b=t$ and $c=u$, so assume that $a<tu$.

> **Added<sub>2</sub>:** When I fixed an the statement below to reflect the fact that $t$ and $u$ are not required to be rational, I didn’t even think about the previous statement, which of course can fail. As others have pointed out, that problem *can’t* be fixed: the assertion is false as it stands, and we really need either strict inequalities or rational $t$ and $u$. The assertion is also flawed in that it doesn’t require $t$ and $u$ to be positive, but that was clearly the intent, so I just used the OP’s original version in which they are assumed to be positive.

Since $t>0$, we can divide through by $t$ to get $\frac{a}t<u$. Let $c$ be any rational between $\frac{a}t$ and $u$, and let $b=\frac{a}c$; it’s straightforward to verify that $b<t$.

Comment: I've just corrected it.

Comment: @Il-seobBae: I’ve made an addition to my answer to address the new information.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Maybe I am missing something, but since $t,u\in\mathbb R$ (they are not necessarily rational) and we want $a,b\in\mathbb Q$, I don't think we can simply put $b=t$ and $c=u$.

Comment: Is $\frac{a}{t}$ necessarily a rational number?

Comment: @Il-seobBae: No, I misread it. Fixed now (barring some mental hiccup, which at this hour is not entirely out of the question).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Is it me that waked you up? Sorry :(

Comment: @Il-seobBae: No, not at all; I just couldn’t get to sleep, so I thought that I’d get up and do something useful.

Comment: I don’t suppose that the downvoter would like to be useful and explain his or her objection; if there’s an error, I’d be happy to fix it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I did not downvote, but I still have my doubts about this part: "If $a=tu$, then of course we can take $b=t$ and $c=u$". (As pointed out in the previous comment.) In fact, I think I have a counterexample and we need to assume $a<tu$ rather $a\le tu$ if we want this claim to be true.

Comment: BTW I should mention that I previously posted "proof" of the claim for which now I think I have counterexample. So anything I say should probably be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I think he just used the fact that $a\in\mathbb{Q}.$ Therefore, he basically refers to the case when $tu\in\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R}.$ I might be wrong.

Comment: @Il-seobBae But from $tu\in\mathbb Q$ we do not get automatically that $t\in\mathbb Q$ and $u\mathbb Q$. See my example with $2=\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt2$.

Comment: You still haven't ruled out $t=u=-1$ in your statement of the proposition.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Oh, I think you're right.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sorry. I have no choice but to withdraw.

Comment: @Il-seobBae: Not a problem. I’ve added enough to it to make it self-contained for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

That proof is busted. The statement that you quote is simply false if $t$ and $u$ are irrational and $a=tu$ is rational (assuming that we require $b$ and $c$ to be non-negative, which is implied in the proof).

I am not saying that it would be difficult to fix the proof, but as it stands, it is invalid.

(I have notified the author, Professor Damron.)